# Does bcrypt have a length limit?

Tags: rust, hash, cryptography, bcrypt

I am using rust. I need to figure out what length limit I should impose on user passwords.

I am using the [bcrypt](https://docs.rs/bcrypt/latest/bcrypt/) crate for hashing passwords.

I read [here](https://www.ory.sh/docs/troubleshooting/bcrypt-secret-length) that:

> BCrypt hashed passwords and secrets have a 72 character limit.

However, somehow, the rust `bcrypt` library is able to generate hashes even for longer passwords. For example, the following 105 character long password also generates the hash.

```
use bcrypt::{DEFAULT_COST, hash};
let hashed = hash("65%&88dd413adb5f4fb4de0ecc01f3a'4'5'65''/$%(908f0321ffdghjgdser4te5y4tregthygrffe4g56gfgdht435hg''32$'21s", DEFAULT_COST);
println!("Hashed: {:?}",hashed);
```

The [documentation](https://docs.rs/bcrypt/latest/bcrypt/fn.hash.html) for the crate doesn't specify any limit.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: The first thing to test is if any characters after position 72 have any impact on the matching.

Comment: It truncates: https://docs.rs/bcrypt/latest/src/bcrypt/lib.rs.html#110-112, so it would be best to hash with something like sha256 first.

Comment: that quite a design flow ! weird choice of this api I would return an error !

Comment: 72-character limit applies to the maximum length of the password input that is used as the input to the bcrypt algorithm. However, bcrypt implementations (C) typically allow passwords of longer length to be hashed by truncating the password before hashing it.

Comment: @Finomnis it's clearly a security risk

Comment: @Stargateur I mean, did you mean flaw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is already discussed at length here:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39849/does-bcrypt-have-a-maximum-password-length

The answer seems to be 50/55/56/72, depending on who you ask. For details, though, read the answers behind the link.

**To sum up:** If you want to be on the safe side, use **50**. However, it seems that up to **72** works. Beyond that, however, the library definitely simply [ignores any further characters](https://docs.rs/bcrypt/latest/src/bcrypt/lib.rs.html#110-112).